# name not defined errors

Tags: python

I continue to try nd run this program but keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bwhite3500\Documents\School\Spring 2011\CITP 110 - Intro to Computer Programming\pet_list.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\bwhite3500\Documents\School\Spring 2011\CITP 110 - Intro to Computer Programming\pet_list.py", line 15, in main
    display_list(pets)
NameError: global name 'display_list' is not defined*
```

Here is my code:

```
import pet_class

def main():
    #get list of pet objects
    pets = make_list()

    #Display the data in a list.
    print 'Here is the data you entered:'
    display_list(pets)


#The make_list function gets data from the user for three pets. The function
# returns a list of pet objects containing the data.

def make_list():
    #create empty list.
    pet_list = []

    #Add three pet objects to the list.
    print 'Enter data for three pets.'
    for count in range (1, 4):
        #get the pet data.
        print 'Pet number ' + str(count) + ':'
        name = raw_input('Enter the pet name:')
        animal=raw_input('Enter the pet animal type:')
        age=raw_input('Enter the pet age:')
        print

        #create a new pet object in memory and assign it
        #to the pet variable

        pet = pet_class.PetName(name,animal,age)

        #Add the object to the list.
        pet_list.append(pet)

    #Return the list
        return pet_list

#The display_list function accepts a list containing pet objects
#as an argument and displays the data stored in each object.

def diplay_list(pet_list):
    for item in pet_list:
        print item.get_name()
        print item.get_animal_type()
        print item.get_age()
        print

#call main function
main()
```

I am new to this and very confused. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check your spelling:

```
def diplay_list(pet_list):
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your function `diplay_list`, not `display_list`.

Comment: wow, theres two hours of my life i'll never get back!! Thanks for the help.